# Find duplicate records depending on first few words in a sepcific column

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to find some duplicate records in a MySQL database depending on the following criteria:

For example, there are two records:

1. `Example text here 123 I am a news 1 duplicate text from any one`
2. `Example text here 123 I am a news 1 duplicate text from any two`

I tried the below, but it only returns for the exact complete title column match:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*) c FROM news_contents GROUP BY title HAVING c > 1
```

What I want is to return the records if the first 5 words are same, like in the example 2 records above: `Example text here 123 I`...

I tried something like this:

```
 SELECT
    title,
    COUNT(*) c
FROM
    news_contents
WHERE
    news_contents.title LIKE CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(news_contents.title, ' ', 4),
        '%'
    )
GROUP BY
    title
HAVING
    c > 1
```

But above is is not returning the results as expected, maybe I am missing something? I have searched a lot but couldn't find any thing.

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work just fine, but the code only check for the first **four** words. If you want the first five, it should be `SUBSTRING_INDEX(news_contents.title, ' ', 5)`

Comment: Scratch that, it doesn't seem to work, but I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by title won't work. If you want to count the duplicates, you need to count by the substring, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 4)) as pt, COUNT(*) c 
   FROM news_contents
   WHERE title LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 4), '%') 
   GROUP BY pt HAVING c > 1
```

but that won't give you each individual duplicated story. For that, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT news_contents.title FROM 
    (SELECT CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 4)) as pt, COUNT(*) c 
        FROM news_contents
        WHERE title LIKE CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 4), '%') 
        GROUP BY pt HAVING c > 1) d, stories 
    WHERE news_contents.title LIKE CONCAT(d.partial_title, '%')
```

and that'll give you each exact title of every duplicated entry that fits the "first four words are the same" criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Might be looking for something like this maybe, You can group by getting the first 5 characters and then compare that to your table to get all the records that match.

```
SELECT LEFT(title,5) N, COUNT(*) C FROM news_contents GROUP BY LEFT(title,5) having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then in order to get your data you can inner join this result with your table:

```
SELECT * FROM news_content nc INNER JOIN (SELECT LEFT(title,5) N, COUNT(*) C FROM news_contents GROUP BY LEFT(title,5) having COUNT(*) > 1) NewsFiltered ON nc.title LIKE NewsFiltered.N + '%'
```

It might not be the fanciest answer but it works.